# Component and beforeFilter not loaded in controller when called from another controller

Tags: cakephp, controller, components

I'm calling controller2 in controller1 to execute some action. Problem is, controller2's action requires a call to its beforeFilter and a Component that is loaded in AppController.

Actually, controller2's action executes well when called directly but I get errors when called in controller1 as follows:

```
App::import('Controller', 'Second');
$Second = new SecondController;
$Second->someAction();
```

Variables that are defined in the Component and in the beforeFilter appear unset.
How could I load an external controller with calling beforeFilter and using my custom Component?

Comment: You should never have to call a controller from another controller. If you do that, you did something wrong. Refactor your code to meet MVC and especially CakePHP's way of handling a basic dispatching process.

Comment: What if I want to split a controller in 2, grouping actions by type, for code clearness sake?

Comment: That's what I often do as well, but that still doesn't justify cross-controller-calls. Everything needs to be in components or the models here - never ever make cross-controller calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case there are few options

```
1. Use request Actions http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::requestAction

2. Move the logic or code you want to execute from SecondCrontroller to common component and use it in both contrllers. 

3. Move the logic or code you want to execute from SecondCrontroller to AppController
```

Comment: Also the model might be a good place (4.) - to complete the list.